# add data with picture angular & laravel

Tags: angular, laravel, api

I have function insertData in angular :

```js
insertData(){
    this.service.insertAnnonce(this.annonce).subscribe(res=>{
        console.log(res);
    })
```

and it works well

and this is my model :

```js
export interface IPost {
    id              :number;
    user_id         :string ;
    picture         :string;
    title           :string;     
    description     :string;      
    price           :number;
    category_id     :number ;
    Modele          :string;  
    BoiteDeVitesse  :string;     
    AnneeModele     :number;      
    Marque          :string;
    YearOfRegistration:number ;
    TypePost        :string;   
    PuissanceFiscale:string;   
    PuissanceDIN    :string;   
    Kilometrage     :number;
    NombreDePortes  :number;
    NombreDePlaces  :number;
    carburant       :string;   
    Permis          :boolean;
    data: IPost[];
}
```

and this is myFunction of **picture** :

```js
onSubmitform(f: NgForm) {
    var myFormData = new FormData();
    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    myFormData.append('image', this.filedata);
    /* Image Post Request */
    this.service.insertAnnonce(this.annonce).subscribe(res=>{
        console.log(res);
    })
    this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/AddImage/', myFormData, {
        headers: headers
    }).subscribe(data => {

    });  
}
```

and it works well also

this is Controller back :

```
  public function add(Request $request){
    $p=new PostVehicule();
    $p->title=        $request->title;
    $p->description=  $request->description;
    $p->price=        $request->price;
    $p->TypePost=     $request->TypePost;
    $p->category=      $request->category;
    $p->Modele=        $request->Modele;
    $p->Marque=        $request->Marque;
    $p->BoiteDeVitesse=$request->BoiteDeVitesse;
    $p->AnneeModele=$request->AnneeModele;
    $p->PuissanceFiscale=$request->PuissanceFiscale;
    $p->Kilometrage=$request->Kilometrage;
    $p->NombreDePortes=$request->NombreDePortes;
    $p->NombreDePlaces=$request->NombreDePlaces;
    $p->carburant=$request->carburant;

 /*   if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $image_file = $request->file('image');
        $img_extension = $image_file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $img_filename = time() . '.' . $img_extension;
        $path ='C:/ionic/data/';
        $image_file->move($path, $img_filename);
        $p->image = $img_filename;
    }*/
    
    if($p->save()){
        //return new PostResource($post); 
        return response()->json(['message'=>'post added successfult']);
 }
}
public function uploadimage(Request $request) {
    $p=new PostVehicule();
    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $image_file = $request->file('image');
        $img_extension = $image_file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $img_filename = time() . '.' . $img_extension;
        $path ='C:/ionic/data/';
        $image_file->move($path, $img_filename);
        $p->image = $img_filename;
    }
    if($p->save()){
        //return new PostResource($post); 
        return response()->json(['message'=>'Image added successfult']);
 }

}
```

so my problem is when I insert the data each one alone like in this picture.

[image]

how can I merge these two functions to have only one result in the database?

Comment: Can I see the code in your backend that stores the form data?

Comment: @XeonNetwork yes I update my question and i add my backend

Comment: if you're calling these methods separately in a sequential manner, you can pass id of generated model to the second function and then updating existing model.

Comment: @MohammadMirsafaei I call the first function in the second like this    ` $p = $this->add($request); ` but there is an new error  "BadMethodCallException: Method Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse::save does not exist.

Comment: It also looks like you are subscribing to observers without keeping track of them to unsubscribe later. Please make sur you either call `pipe(first())` or unsubscribe to your subscriptions. This will prevent any memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you use 2 separate functions for this, but the problem is you're making new object in both functions (`$p=new PostVehicule();`). If you insist on writing 2 functions, you should pass same object you created at first to the second object. `$p = $this->add($request);` you mentioned in comments doesn't return a PostVehicule object, it returns a http response. You should change it like:

```
if($p->save()){
        return $p;
 }
```

Comment: I change with what you say and i get successfult but in the database he just add all data without the picture

Comment: if I add the content of the function picture in the first function it work good and in the database in added good also but in the frontEnd he dosen't work

Comment: @rachedcherif Can you explain what the error is in the frontend when you add the code to upload code to the add method? (Also, don't feel afraid to provide more info; saying "the frontend doesn't work" isn't going to give me much info.)

Comment: @XeonNetwork in the frontend the problem is when i add the post with his picture  , the picture added in the database but the the rest of data no    ,       
 this is my function :

Comment: `insertData(){
    let formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append('image', this.filedata);
    formdata.append('data',JSON.stringify(this.annonce));

    this.service.insertAnnonce(formdata).subscribe(res=>{
      console.log(res);
    }) `                                                                                                      `                               
 filedata:any;
    fileEvent(event){
        this.filedata = event.target.files[0];
    }`

Comment: @rachedcherif Check out my answer I wrote to you. Let me know if it works. If it does, read the documentation for the Laravel filesystem

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best code, but I'll give it a shot.
This will only store it inside your public folder of your Laravel application.

Make sure to import `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage`

Checkout the documentation for the filesystem API here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // This will store it in the public folder of your root (every file stored in public is exposed to the internet)
        if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            Storage::disk('local')->putFileAs('/public', $request->image, $request->image->getClientOriginalName());
        }

        // sorry man. I don't feel like fixing this block of code at the moment (I'm supposed to be studying)
        $p = new PostVehicule();
        $p->title =        $request->title;
        $p->description =  $request->description;
        $p->price =        $request->price;
        $p->TypePost =     $request->TypePost;
        $p->category =      $request->category;
        $p->Modele =        $request->Modele;
        $p->Marque =        $request->Marque;
        $p->BoiteDeVitesse = $request->BoiteDeVitesse;
        $p->AnneeModele = $request->AnneeModele;
        $p->PuissanceFiscale = $request->PuissanceFiscale;
        $p->Kilometrage = $request->Kilometrage;
        $p->NombreDePortes = $request->NombreDePortes;
        $p->NombreDePlaces = $request->NombreDePlaces;
        $p->carburant = $request->carburant;
        $p->image = $request->hasFile('image') ? $request->image->getClientOriginalName() : NULL;

        if ($p->save())
        {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Post created successfully']);
        }
    }
```